# how to create expandablelist view activity with checkboxes?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am following an expandable list tutorial and the expandable functionality is working fine:
http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/05/expandable-lists.html

I don't know which event to implement. I need to handle checkboxes in a list when I click on checkbox when it expands the list. How do I distinguish a list click with checkbox placed in an expandable list?

Or, kindly refer me to tutorial same as expandablelist view with checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here...

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html